# Ionic 4 View PDF

Tags: ionic4

Under android 10 (Samsung A50), I installed the document viewer plugin to be able to open a pdf that I have on a website.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-document-viewer
npm install @ ionic-native / document-viewer
```

When I try to open the pdf, it offers me to open it with **google play store or galaxy store**.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong, and if there is any way to open the pdf directly, without choosing which program to open it with.

I send used code, and I also inform them that with fileopener it works correctly, except that it asks me if I want to open with the pdf viewer or another program, and I want the opening of the pdf to be direct, without that step of choosing a program.

```
 Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.0
 Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
 @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
 Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
 Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
 *********************************************
async pdf2() {
      const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
        title: 'My PDF',
        openWith:   { enabled: true},
        bookmarks : {
          enabled : true
      },
      search : {
          enabled : true
      },
      autoClose: {
          onPause : true
      }
      }

      let path = null;
      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        path = this.file.documentsDirectory;
      } else {
        path = this.file.dataDirectory;
      }
      const transfer = this.transfer.create();
      transfer.download('https://www.zzzzz.com/site/pdfs/blabla.pdf', path + 'myfile.pdf').then(entry => {
        let url = entry.toURL();
        this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', options);
      })
}
```

thanks!!

Comment: You can user `File Opener` or `In App Browser` plugin

Comment: thanks for answering! Is there any way that fileopener does it directly without asking me what program I open the pdf with?